# Java multi threading - Passing a data-structure to the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The application, I am writing, generates an ArrayList of Characters at certain stage. At this stage, I am trying create a thread to process this ArrayList. The problem is how do I pass this ArrayList to the thread

Descriptive Code:

```
class thisApp {
    /* Some initial processing creates an ArrayList - aList */

    Runnable proExec = new ProcessList (); //ProcessList implements Runnable
    Thread th = new Thread(proExec);
}
```

Descriptive Code For ProcessList:

```
public class ProcessList implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      /* Access the ArrayList - aList - and do something upon */
    }
}
```

My problem is: How do I pass and access aList in run()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass `aList` to the `ProcessList`'s constructor, which can retain the reference until it's needed:

```
class thisApp {
    /* Some initial processing creates an ArrayList - aList */

    Runnable proExec = new ProcessList (aList);
    Thread th = new Thread(proExec);
}

public class ProcessList implements Runnable {
    private final ArrayList<Character> aList;
    public ProcessList(ArrayList<Character> aList) {
      this.aList = aList;
    }
    public void run() {
      /* use this.aList */
    }
}
```

**N.B.** If `aList` will be accessed concurrently by multiple threads, with one or more threads modifying it, all relevant code will need to be `synchronized`.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the list will be simultaneously accessed. Anyways, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add an argument to the `ProcessList` constructor.

```
public class ProcessList implements Runnable
{    
    private final List<Foo> aList;

    public ProcessList(List<Foo> aList)
    {
        this.aList = aList;
    }

    public void run()
    {
      System.out.println(aList.size());
    }
}
```

You'll have to be careful about concurrent access to the list if any other threads have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the List final, but it's better to pass it in to your Runnable object.

```
public class ProcessList implements Runnable {
    List<Character> list;
    public ProcessList(List<Character> list){
    this.list = list;
    }
    public void run() {
         this.list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"You could make the List final"_ - I don't get what you're saying there.

Comment: I was suggesting that if the list was in scope then by making it final you could reference it from within the threads run method without passing it in.