# Pass variables into Thread on the go?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, methods

I'm not sure if I'm just missing something here, but is it possible to pass a variable into a running `Thread` in java? The variables may change and may need to be resent into the same thread.

Any tutorials on the matter or examples would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309732/java-multi-threading-passing-a-data-structure-to-the-thread

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass a variable[s] which will be dynamic and change over time.

Comment: May be you try adding more specific about your problem

Comment: Nit: Variables are *never* passed in Java. Only values are (objects are a type of value, but I don't want to get into a call-semantics game here). Some objects can be mutated and/or act as containers.

Comment: @pst If you really want to nitpick, you never pass objects, either -- you can only pass references to objects.

Comment: @yshavit I hold that as merely a terminology issue when talking about high-level semantics -- hence my pre-emptive parenthetical note :-) I prefer call-by-object-sharing over call-by-value[-of-the-reference] and consider "how" objects are named (e.g. it is the "values of their references" that are passed/stored) as an implementation detail (this *does not* introduce a conflict with call-by-object-sharing). If I was discussing the *design* of the JVM/bytecode then the latter, call-by-value[-of-the-reference], is clearly more appropriate, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two easy choices:

- ConcurrentLinkedQueue: this can act like a  threadsafe pipe between two threads. On thread feeds the queue as needed, the other reads as
  needed, either blocking or polling.
- use shared variables and flags, and use synchronization primitives to ensure that a thread is not reading while another is writing.

Comment: One thing to watch out for with a ConcurrentLinkedQueue is that it's unbounded, so if your requests (puts) are coming in much faster than you can process (take) them, you could run out of memory.

Comment: Your're right,  LinkedBlockingQueue may be a better choice, although ConcurrentLinkedQueue has a size() method so you can bound it yourself or write a wrapper. LinkedBlockingQueue if you want to block, ConcurrentLinkedQueue if you want to poll and do other work if nothing is available...

Comment: [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)s can be used to offer/poll or put/get and so are generally more flexible than the CncurrentLinkedQueue. There are several flavours, both bounded and unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the way to do this is to have the thread know about a thread-safe structure which other threads also know about. Take a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) classes.

For instance, both threads know about an instance of [`BlockingQueue<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). One thread puts `Foo`s to the queue, and the other takes the `Foo`s off that queue and does something with them.