# Public variables call in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, variables

I got some error when i try to call a public variable in my thread.

First my Code:

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
public String number;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        number = "123";

        t.start();

    }
    public Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SET_TEXT, number));

        }
    });
    public Hander handler = new Handler() {
         [blabla...]
    }
}
```

Error i get:
/AndroidRuntime(3737): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1

i believe its a nullpointer exception or something.

what do i wrong?

Thanks,
Prexx

Comment: "i believe its a nullpointer exception or something." - no, it's a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` - you've logged that! Unfortunately, you haven't given us the full stack trace, or included the code in the handler.

Comment: Damn, got the answer, thanks anyways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309732/java-multi-threading-passing-a-data-structure-to-the-thread

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Show your actual code and a full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsExeption` right there.  Chances are you're trying to substring something with an invalid index or similar.  At any rate, I doubt the threading is to blame.  Unless you can give us more, information about exactly where the error is happening (indicate a line number or something) I doubt you'll get much more than that for help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. it works now. i postet my solution in a comment above. i created my own Runnable and in the constructor i set the string iam using while my thread is running. maybe your right, that there is an invalid index or something. but the reason this happens is that i cannot access on a public variable in my class from my thread..